# Transitivity of an invariant of finitely generated field extensions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, fields

For a finitely generated extension of fields $K/k$, let us define "$S_{K/k}$" to be the minimum of the degrees $[K:\ell]$ where $\ell/k$ ranges over the purely transcendental subextensions of $K$ with $\mathrm{tr.deg}(K/k) = \mathrm{tr.deg}(\ell/k)$.

> Does there exist a tower $K_{3}/K_{2}/K_{1}$ of finitely generated extensions such that $S_{K_{3}/K_{1}} \ne S_{K_{3}/K_{2}} \cdot S_{K_{2}/K_{1}}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think so. Let $P\in \mathbb{C}[t]$ be a polynomial of degree $\geq 3$, with no multiple root and $P(0)\neq 0$.
Take $K_1=\mathbb{C}$, $K_2=\mathbb{C}(t)[x]/(x^2-P(t))$,  $K_3=K_2[u]/(u^2-t)$. Then $S_{K_2/K_1}=2$, $S_{K_3/K_2}=[K_3:K_{2}]=2$, but $S_{K_3/K_1}=2$ because $K_3=\mathbb{C}(u)[x]/(x^2-P(u^2))$.